# Cannot resolve column name error for column passed as strings - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a peculiar problem. I am trying to select some columns from a dataframe using automatically generated strings. While the selects are working fine if I pass them directly, if I put the same expression in strings and pass the string to select, it fails with the error "Cannot resolve column name given list of columns". It is somehow adding backticks ` to the string and trying to find the full string as a column name (instead of evaluating the string expression and using that as a column name)

Examples below:

This works, historyJoinedDF is a dataframe which is an output of an outer join between two dataframes:

```
historyJoinedDF.select(
        currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")
      ).show()
```

This does not work:

```
val test = """currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")"""
      historyJoinedDF.select(
      test
     .show()
```

Fails with:

```
cannot resolve '`currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")`' given input columns:
```

Not sure if it matters but my dataframe is the output of a full outer join between two dataframes with the same schema (thus the need for qualifying the column names with DF names).

Edit: adding output of currentUnmatchedDF.show(false) & historyJoinedDF .show(false) below, both have few hundred columns (which are same) so showing only the columns mentioned in the question.

[image: currentUnmatchedDF]

[image: historyJoinedDF]

Comment: currentUnmatchedDF is UDF or Dataframe ?

Comment: currentUnmatchedDF is a dataframe.

Comment: then how you are selecting columns from historyJoinedDF dataframe using currentUnmatchedDF dataframe? it is not good practice.. can you explain the schema of both dataframe

Comment: The first code snippet is an example of how Select is working fine.

I have edited the code to reflect same dataframe in both examples, please review.

Comment: Can you also please show both dataframe value historyJoinedDF & currentUnmatchedDF.    currentUnmatchedDF.show(false) & historyJoinedDF .show(false)

Comment: Added snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

select method takes column names as param. so you should do something like

```
someDf.select("sessiondetail_sessionid")
```

or if you want to get columns of other df and select them in some df you shoud use

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
someDf.select(otherDf.columns.map(col): _*) //: _* transforms collection to varag
```

but you are trying to get column with literal name

```
currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")
```

Comment: Select takes both String and Col. Also, please see the two examples I have quoted, it works just fine with the hardcoded string, it just doesn't work with a string variable.

Comment: sure, cause string should be column name, and you are passing piece of code inside string. just print test val from your example and you see it

Comment: But that piece of code evaluates to a string and works fine if passed directly as a string and not as a string val.

Comment: that piece of code doesnt evaluate to a string. it evaluates to a Column. you can print it and check

Comment: and even if it would evaluate, you should be doing `val str = s"${currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")}"`, but you are doing `val str = """currentUnmatchedDF("sessiondetail_sessionid").as("sessiondetail_sessionid")"""`